# Is it safe to start thread execution in onDestroy of a Activity/IME?

Tags: android, android-activity, thread-safety, android-input-method, android-thread

I am creating a keyboard. I need to do some database intensive operation at onDestroy of my IME. SO I made a Runnable and am calling it in the onDestory as shown, but I'm not sure wether it is safe to do so. Is it?

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        convexthesavedlists();
        Runnable rn=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                edata.addthislist(MyInputMethodService.this,englist1);
            }
        };
        Thread th=new Thread(rn);
        th.start();
    }
```

Comment: "I need to do some database intensive operation at onDestroy of my IME" -- why? Why not update the database as you go?

Comment: it takes a lot of time to load the database, and every time i do this task, i have to load data again from database, so I'm trying to do this as a alternative